# Any documentation on angular google maps clustering options?

Tags: google-maps, angularjs

Hi I am using the Angular Google Maps library available here https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps. it seems pretty powerful but it lacks exhaustive documentation... I am trying to cluster my  markers but I can't find a working example of how to do it. Did anyone manage to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is a bit old, but maybe this can be useful for someone with the same issue.

Here is a simple example from the code I used:

On my controller, I generate a markers array with this structure:

```
 var markers = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++ ){

        var newMarker = {
            id: parseInt(i),
            latitude: parseFloat(someData[i].latitude),
            longitude: parseFloat(someData[i].longitude),
            showWindow: false,
            title: "Marker"+i,
        }

        newMarker.onClicked = function () {
            alert(newMarker.id);
        }

        markers.push(newMarker);
    }

    $scope.markers = markers;
```

Then on the view:

```
<google-map center="map.center" draggable="true" options=map.options zoom="map.zoom">

        <markers models="markers" coords="'self'" doCluster=true click="'onClicked'">
        </markers>

    </google-map>
```

Comment: If someone is checking this, it doesn't work with the last release (2.0.12). You will need to use the [master branch](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps)

Comment: Please check the docs, I believe directives names have changed quite a bit:  http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

Answer (score 0):

It is built into the default example.

Here view, https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/example.html#L75-L76

controller,

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/assets/scripts/controllers/example.js#L28-563